# Optimal scope for filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'd like to write fast scope for filter my restaurants.

I do something like this

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.all
@restaurants = filter(@restaurants)

def filter(restaurants)
    restaurants = restaurants.filter('types', params[:type].split(','))          unless params[:type].nil?
    restaurants = restaurants.filter('cuisines', params[:cuisine].split(','))    unless params[:cuisine].nil? 
    restaurants = restaurants.filter('facilities', params[:facility].split(',')) unless params[:facility].nil? 
    restaurants = restaurants.filter('services', params[:service].split(','))    unless params[:service].nil? 
    restaurants = restaurants.filter('prices', params[:price].split(','))        unless params[:price].nil?
    return restaurants
end
```

where filter is:

```
  scope :filter, lambda{|type_name, type_id| includes(type_name.to_sym).where(["#{type_name}.id in (?)", type_id]) }
```

so... when i get url:

```
.../search?service=1,2,3
```

i get restaurants with service 1 OR 2 OR 3, but i'd like to get restaurants with services 1 AND 2 AND 3.
How can i do this as fast as it possible is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` in SQL is *always* going to be an `OR` operation. You'll need to split the param first and then do multiple filters. Also, `all` sidesteps the lazy loading of AREL so you're loading everything first and then filtering from there. Bad mojo. :)

Have you considered doing this as a route?

```
# restaurant.rb
scope :filter, lambda{|type_name, type_id| includes(type_name.to_sym).where("#{type_name}_id" => type_id) }

# routes.rb
match 'restaurants/search/*query', "restaurants_controller#search"

# restaurants_controller.rb
def search
    query = params[:query]
    query.delete_at(-1) if query.length % 2 > 0 #Otherwise we'll get an exception for providing an odd number of elements.
    search_hash = Hash[*query].symbolize_keys
    @restaurants = Restaurant.scoped
search_hash.each do |key, value|
    value.split(",").each do |v|
        @restaurants.filter(key, v)
    end
    end
end
```

Then your search URLs become something like:

```
/search/service/1,2,3/type/3,4,5
```

You'd need to do some sanity checking like making sure `key` is a property on `Restaurant` model, but this should work. Also, I've proofread this a few times to make sure I didn't miss anything, but this is untested code that might have bugs or typos. Caveat emptor. :)

Comment: There are problems with delete_at (no operation delete_at for String /service/1,2,3) etc :(

Comment: D'oh! In Rails 2 I think it passes as an array. Try splitting to get an array of path components.